# Kion signifas «pro neniu kialo mi akceptis la inviton»?

Tags: negation

Por mi, mi nature emus diri frazon kiel «pro neniu kialo mi akceptis la inviton» eble pro influo de la angla en kiu mi povus diri «I accepted the invite for no reason». Tio signifus ke mi ja akceptis la inviton, kvankam ne estis kialo por tio. Tamen, en [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neado.html) mi legis la jenan frazon pri neni-vortoj:

> Por nei oni povas ankaŭ uzi tabelvortojn je NENI. NENI-vorto sufiĉas por nei la ĉefverbon, kaj do la tutan frazon. La pozicio de NENI-vorto normale ne gravas, ĝi tamen neas la tutan frazon

Do, ĉu laŭ tio, en mia ekzempla frazo, la tuta frazo estas neita kaj oni devus kompreni ke mi *ne* akceptis la inviton (ĉar ne estis kialo por akcepti)?

Mi faris etan enketon pri tiu frazo ĉe Telegram, kaj 100% de la 5 respondintoj diris ke ili komprenus ke mi ja akceptis la inviton. Se malmultaj homoj komprenas la PMEG-an sencon, ĉu oni povus diri ke tio estas nur teorio kaj en la praktiko ĝi ne validas?

Comment: Mi scivolas pri la nacia lingvo de la respondintoj ĉe Telegram.  Ĉu ili ĉefe estis parolantoj de la angla?

Comment: @Lee Estas malfacile scii kiu respondis sed estis almenaŭ du nederlandanoj kaj ruso en la diskuto antaŭ la enketo.

Comment: pro neniu kialo = nenial

Answer (score 8):

Pli sube sur tiu paĝo:

> NENI-vortoj normale neas la tutan frazon sendepende de la vortordo, sed iafoje ankaŭ NENI-vorto povas validi por nur parto de frazo. Tiam la kunteksto kaj la vortordo devas tute klare tion montri

Ekzemplo, el Jesaja ĉap. 52:

> En Egiptujon iam iris Mia popolo, por loĝi tie kelktempe, kaj la Asiriano **pro nenio** ĝin premis. [Angle: *the Assyrian oppressed them without cause* = senkiale]

Kontraste, Zamenhof uzis *per nenio* por nei frazon. El *Korta koko kaj ventkoko*:

> ĝi per nenio similis al la flirtantaj birdoj sub la ĉielo

Oni devas uzi logikon kaj kuntekston. Se ago verŝajnas, kaj evidente eblas sen la neata parto, ni rajtas supozi ke la *neni-* koncernas nur la parton. Tamen, oni devus strebi eviti tian ambaŭsencecon per pli bona stilo.

- *Mi neniam vizitis.* Ne eblas viziti sen tempo, do mi ne vizitis.
- *Mi manĝis nenion.* Ne eblas manĝi sen manĝaĵo, do mi ne manĝis.
- *Mi manĝis per nenia manĝilo.* Eblas manĝi sen manĝilo, do mi ja manĝis.
- *Mi vojaĝis kun neniom da mono.* Eblas vojaĝi sen mono, do mi ja vojaĝis.
- *Ĉe la balo, multaj invitis min, sed mi dancis kun neniu.* Oni ne rajtas danci sola ĉe balo, do mi ne dancis.
- *Ne licis danci en la ĝardeno, do mi iradis sola en la arbaron, kie mi dancadis kun neniu.* Mi ja dancis.

Fojfoje, eblas uzi *-us* por nei la tuton sufiĉe klare:

- *Multaj invitis min, sed mi dancus kun neniu.* aŭ *...akceptis neniun.*
- *Mi hontis kaj nenial dancus.*

Answer (score 5):

Se oni ja akceptis la inviton, estas preferinde diri "Sen kialo mi akceptis la inviton". Ĉar la formo kun "neniu" principe devas signifi, ke oni ne akceptis la inviton.

Comment: Kiel gxi povus signifi tion? Estas diferenco inter "Kiu akceptis la inviton? Neniu." kaj "Mi akceptis la inviton. Kial? Pro neniu kialo."

Answer (score 2):

Mi ne pensas ke en tiu frazo la vorto *neniu* neas aŭ jesas ĉu oni akceptis la inviton. Laŭ mia kompreno, ĝi simple neas ke estis ia kialo por agi tiel aŭ alie. Ni povas revortigi la frazon jene: *estis neniu kialo, pro kiu mi akceptis la inviton*. Alivorte: *mi akceptis la inviton senkiale*.

**PS:** La frazo *li estis mortigita de neniu* ne nepre signifas ke li ne estis mortigita, nur ke neniu mortigis lin. Ankoraŭ eblas ke alia kaŭzo mortigis lin, ekz-e akcidento. Kvankam gramatike la vorto *neniu* povas nei la tutan frazon, la finfina senco dependas de la kunteksto. Manke de kunteksto, oni esprimu sin kiel eble plej klare, evitante dubon aŭ ambiguecon, krom se la celo estu tia.

Fakte, en ĉi tiu okazo, akcidento mortigis lin:

> Mia onklo ne mortis per natura morto, sed li tamen ne mortigis sin mem kaj ankaŭ estis mortigita de neniu; unu tagon, promenante apud la
>   reloj de fervojo, li falis sub la radojn de veturanta vagonaro kaj
>   mortiĝis.
>
> (Ekzercaro de la Fundamento, §39)

Comment: Kiam oni revortumas la frazon, oni ne plu priparolas la saman gramatikon.

Answer (score 0):

La frazo, *pro neniu kialo mi akceptis la inviton*, signifas

> Mi ne akceptis la inviton

ĉar PMEG diras

> li estis mortigita **de neniu** = Li ne estis mortigita.

Tio signifas, ke NENI-vortoj en prepoziciaj frazoj(=prepositional phrases) ankaŭ neas frazojn. *pro neniu kialo* estas tia prepozicia frazo, do la frazo estas neita.